# Is there a way to receive messages through XMPP in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, xmpp

Is there a way to receive Facebook chat/messages through XMPP in Rails? I've checked with xmpp4r_facebook but so far I can only send messages with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set a message callback using add_message_callback. The echo example from xmpp4r should get you started: https://github.com/ln/xmpp4r/blob/master/data/doc/xmpp4r/examples/basic/echo.rb.